# Return success message to UI and do background process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, webapi

I am working on a scenario where I will be posting files to an external API from webapi. For that, I am using `IFormFile`. I want to return the success message (Upload in Progress) to the front end, and continue with the backend upload process, as it takes near to 1-2 min.

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve that?

I am using the below code where I am getting the error on the `files.OpenReadStream()` line

```
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
content.Add(new StreamContent(files.OpenReadStream()),
  "file", files.FileName);
content.Add(new StringContent(json), "employee_details");
using (var response = await httpclient.PostAsync(_host, content))
{
    string apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkillDbDTO>(apiresponse);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question by code on which you are working.

Comment: Have a look at this, I use this heavily for all background processing without keeping enduser wait
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: updated my code in question

Comment: I looked at your code and you can write the background task for it. Did you have look at link i posted?

Comment: Sohan - Will the above link code return files processing... alert message to user and then continue the background process? - Please help me share if you have any working code

Comment: Yes sure it will. I am doing same. I notify user upfront and process request in background
I am processing for 1 million request submitted by single user
I will try to post something

Comment: Also what is the exact error you are getting,
 Error files.OpenReadStream()  does not explain